# Difference between these two CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between the selectors `div.red > p` and `div.red p`?

Please point to the key difference between these CSS selectors.

#### HTML

```
<div class="red"><p></p><div class="blue"><p></p></div>
```

Does the first selector select only the first `<p>` element?

Comment: [Google "div > p vs div p"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+div+%3E+p+vs+div+p) yields several results

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider the following [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML):

```
<div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
    </p>
    <p>4</p>
</div>
<p>5</p>
```

`div > p` will only select direct descendants: 1, 4 and the one with the `p` elements nested in it.

`div p` will select all p tags within a div: 1 2 3 4.

Answer (score 4):

```
div > p
```

This will select only `p` elements that are a child of `div`

```
div p
```

This will select all descendent (i.e. children, children's children etc) `p` elements of a `div`

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) for more info.

Comment: The term for the `>` is "child combinator"

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of explaining that is to just make a simple [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zQ54P/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="id">
    <p>First text</p>
    <div>
        <p>Second text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#id > p { background: red; }
div#id p { color: green; }
```

Only the first text has red background, because `>` takes only `p` that is direct child of `div#id`. The second one is not matched because there is another `div` between `div#id` and `p`.

However, they both are green, because `div#id p` matches all `p` that are descendant to `div#id`, no matter how deep in the Document Object Model.

Answer (score 0):

The first selector says "All `p` tags that are a direct child of `div`". The second says "All `p` tags inside of `div`, regardless of whether they are children, grandchildren" and so on.